# iPhone - Populating an array with the content of compressed plist file

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, compression, plist

Let's say I have a plist file, and I want to compress it. I have a method that loads this compressed file, uncompress it, and put the result into a NSString.

How may I convert that NSString into an array as simple as it can be done with those lines when the plist is not compressed :

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray* arrayOfDatas = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the file into an `NSData` then use:

```
+ (id)propertyListWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSPropertyListReadOptions)opt format:(NSPropertyListFormat *)format error:(NSError **)error
```

where `NSPropertyListFormat` is `NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0`

Creating to `NSData` to write out is:

```
+ (NSData *)dataWithPropertyList:(id)plist format:(NSPropertyListFormat)format options:(NSPropertyListWriteOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error
```

Example (not tested):

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"plist"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSError *error;
NSArray* plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:NULL error:&error];

NSData *propertyListSerializedData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:plist format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:&error];
[propertyListSerializedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```